# Why is javascript variable overlapping?

Tags: javascript

My question is why I'm having issues with declaring these variables. It works fine until "priceAdj" and the only thing I can find to explain that, Is that Javascript thinks it's still part of the previous variable. But I have no idea why it would think that because isn't the comma supposed to seperate them? I know I could just declare var again, But my code won't let me pass it up.

**CODE:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var average = (80),
  totalDay = (100),
  priceInt = (3000),
  adjust = ((totalDay*priceInt)/average),
  percent = ((priceInt/adjust)-1),
  pLimit = 1+(percent)*(percent)*((percent)/Math.abs(percent)),
  priceAdj = (priceInt*(pLimit)),
  priceDigits = (Math.ceil(priceAdj*100));
  Logger.log(priceDigits);
}
```

Comment: `(Math.ceil(priceAdj*100)/);` typo - `/` or either u miss something atfer.

Comment: http://www.uxebu.com/index.html%3Fp=1135.html don't do that, what the `comma`?

Comment: First, I think your OCD would make you use var for each variable, not omit it and take the shortcut. Next, your declarations seem useless, if all you are doing is a mathematical calculation on static values. Just write the algorithm as a single expression.

Comment: Ummmm... maybe I dont code the same way you want to? I thought people were supposed to have an open mind here. All the 'var's all over the place irritate me, and its not as easy to follow if its all jumbled together like you're suggesting.

Comment: You dont need brackets around Number literals, just sayin...

Comment: @corn3lius Okay I see the points there, so maybe I'll do that, as ugly as it looks to me, but I'd still like to know why this isn't working. Just cause.

Comment: @Jonasw I know, I was just putting them there in an attempt to fix it because It felt like something was overlapping. Obviously they didnt help.

Comment: What occurs at `priceAdj` that is not right—what errors/unexpected behavior do you experience?

Comment: @AndrewSiplas I ended up answering my own question and posted what I was seeing. I guess its a visual error and not an actual code error.

Comment: I am not sure about javascript (since its not as strict) , but in other languages when all the Vars are declared on one line. the declaration is not completed until it sees the end of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I sort of know whats wrong.. the code actually does work, but I thought it didn't because what I'm using didn't make it the same color as the other variables for some reason. I don't know why that is, but I guess that isn't a question for here.A screenshot of the code is below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDK5a.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a syntax error of "Unexpected token )" when I run it in the console. You have an extraneous "/" in this line: `(Math.ceil(priceAdj*100)/);`

Comment: I fixed that, that wasnt supposed to be there. my question still remains.

Comment: oh wait... I think i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your var declaration is correct. 
You can test it in codepen with the following sample which returns 288000 for priceDigits:

```
function myFunction() {
  var average = (80),
  totalDay = (100),
  priceInt = (3000),
  adjust = ((totalDay*priceInt)/average),
  percent = ((priceInt/adjust)-1),
  pLimit = 1+(percent)*(percent)*((percent)/Math.abs(percent)),
  priceAdj = (priceInt*(pLimit)),
  priceDigits = (Math.ceil(priceAdj*100));
  //Logger.log(priceDigits);
  return priceDigits;
}
$('body').text(myFunction());
```

See corresponding codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEPMLb.
Maybe your problem comes from your last instruction.

Comment: You don’t need a code pen, Stack Overflow gives you a code snippet you could include in your answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I did not know. Thank you for the tip ;)